# Using images for header icons in fullcalendar

Tags: css, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

I'm using Adam Shaw's fullcalendar jquery plugin and it works really well, after speaking to the graphic designer he wishes to use images instead of fullcalendar's prev,next,today and the three view icons (month, week, day).

Using firebug I've isolated that the "prev" icon, for instance, is using the span class

```
fc-button-prev
```

However, when I go to the css and create the class applying a background image:

```
.fc-button-prev {
   background-image: url('../images/prev.png');
}
```

Nothing happens.

Any ideas would be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you have to define `display:block` in your class like this:

```
.fc-button-prev {
   background-image: url('../images/prev.png');
display:block;
width:50px;
height:50px;
}
```

because `span` is an `inline element`. So, `inline element` is not take `width` , `height`, `vertical margin & padding` in it.

Comment: Inline elements **can** have padding: http://jsfiddle.net/tCaKx/1 ...and backticks in SO posts are for code, not highlighting or emphasis.

Comment: @WesleyMurch; padding add in the width of the inline element not height http://jsfiddle.net/tCaKx/2/

Answer (score 0):

In fullcalendar 2.x I had to use the following CSS to change "previous" button image:

```
.fc-prev-button {
    background-image: url(../img/icon_arrow_left.png) !important;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    width: 50px !important;
    height: 50px !important;
    background-color: transparent !important;
    border: none !important;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}
.fc-prev-button span {
    display: none;
}
```